# What work environment perfectly fits for an INFJ?

Tags: work-environment, colleagues

I am really curious about this. I am INFJ and it is hard for me to blend in with my current workmates.

Comment: Could you be more concrete about your personality? Meyers-Briggs is a...questionable metric and although somewhat usefull as an indicator you could improve the question by giving examples of when your personality clashed with colleagues.

Comment: Please be specific about the problems.  There is nothing fundamentally wrong with an INFJ personality.

Comment: I had to search the internet for the term *INFJ*. Questions on this site are supposed to be self contained. Is this a well established term?

Answer (score 4):

The same work environment as for anyone else, because [Myers-Briggs type indicators have little to none scientific validity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%E2%80%93Briggs_Type_Indicator#Criticism). They tell you about as much about yourself as horoscopes or those "What Harry Potter character are you?" quizzes you encounter on Facebook.

You might want to analyze for yourself what problems you *actually* have with your current workmates and how those problems could be solved or avoided. Don't let some questionable psych-test define you. You are an individual, not a category. Consider for yourself what **you** want in a workplace.

If you need any help with any specific problems you have in your current work environment, feel free to post these as new questions.

Comment: Please don't take the Wikipedia criticisms section as a definitive and scientific statement about something's worth.

Comment: @DJClayworth the wiki criticism is well-sourced. Criticism of one of the sources is welcome, but don’t use the ‘wiki=bad’ argument that teachers used 20 years ago.

Comment: Too long for a comment so here we go. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130786/myers-briggs